# Handling hardware search to show searchview in ActionbarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I'm wondering how to do that : when the user press hardware search button, it's open a search view in the actionbar.

Basically I have an activity hosting fragments.
One fragment add to the ActionbarSherlock a searchview, it's working fine:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu,
        MenuInflater inflater) {

    if(searchView==null)
        searchView = new SearchView(getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());

    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);


        menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.string.search, Menu.NONE, R.string.search)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_search_api_holo_light)
        .setActionView(searchView)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

I think I can also catch the hardware key in the FragmentActivity with

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {

    //DO SOMETHING

    return super.onSearchRequested();
}
```

But I do not see how to open the searchview when the hardware search button is pressed.

Any hint ?

Thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here how I managed to use the hardware search key to open the searchview in the sherlock actionbar :

In my SherlockFragmentActivity :

```
private Menu ABSMenu;

@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ABSMenu = menu;
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {

    MenuItem mi = ABSMenu.findItem(R.string.search); // R.string.search is the id of the searchview
    if(mi!=null){
    if(mi.isActionViewExpanded())
     {
            mi.collapseActionView();
     }else 
     {
            mi.expandActionView();  
     }
    }

    return super.onSearchRequested();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the search view and collapse it like

```
searchView.setIconified(false); 
searchView.setIconified(true);
```

This way you can programatically invoke search view

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I could not use that to achieve what I wanted to do.